# How to select only those comments where associated posts's privacy is 0

Tags: mysql

I have a table "Posts" that looks like this-

```
------------------------------------
id  |  Title | Date | Privacy 
1   | abc    | 2016 | 0
2   | xyz    | 2015 | 1
```

And another table "comments" that looks like this-

```
------------------------------------
id  | post_id | content | Date   
1   |  2       |  abc    | 2016 
2   |  1       |  xyz    | 2015
```

I need to select all the comments -

a) whose post's privacy is 0 
b) Where comments.content is like '%keyword%' 
c) order by comments.date 
d) Limit and offset values

Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
SELECT content 
FROM comments C
INNER JOIN Posts P ON P.id = C.post_id
WHERE content like '%keyword%' 
AND Privacy = 0
ORDER BY C.Date
```

Please explain what you mean with: "*d) Limit and offset values*"

Answer (score 0):

You should first search for an answer already given on stack overflow or just make a google search.

Anyway here is your answer

```
select * from comments where 
content like '%keyword%' and
post_id in ( select id from Posts where Privacy = 0)
order by Date
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I knew this would have already been answered but was not able to phrase the keywords correctly. Thanks for your response anyway.